# JSON data encoded are repeated

Tags: php, json, mysqli

I have a database with several data in it, but they are unique of course. These data are inside each table, **telcoCall**, **telcoData**, **telcoSMS**, depending on its class.

I then use `json_encode` to merge these data into 1 single array. Inside **telcoCall**, the data are in proper place. However, **telcoData** and **telcoSMS** are messy. The data inside these tables are being duplicated. This is how it looks,

[image]

Here's the code:

```
<?PHP
include '../initialization.php';

$mysqli = @mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $db);

$query = 'SELECT t.*, c.*, d.*, s.* '.
         'FROM telco t '.
            'INNER JOIN telcoCall c ON t.telcoId = c.telcoId '.
            'INNER JOIN telcoData d ON t.telcoId = d.telcoId '.
            'INNER JOIN telcoSMS s ON t.telcoId = s.telcoId '.
                'ORDER BY t.telcoName, c.callName, d.dataName, s.smsName';

//setup array to hold information
$telcos = array();

//setup holders for the different types so that we can filter out the data
$telcoId = 0;
$callId = 0;
$dataId = 0;
$smsId = 0;

//setup to hold our current index
$telcoIndex = -1;
$callIndex = -1;
$dataIndex = -1;
$smsIndex = -1;

if ($result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query)) {
    //go through the rows
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        if($telcoId != $row['telcoId']) {
            $telcoIndex++;
            $callIndex = -1;
            $dataIndex = -1;
            $smsIndex = -1;
            $telcoId = $row['telcoId'];

            //add the console
            $telcos[$telcoIndex]['Telco'] = $row['telcoName'];

            //setup the information array
            $telcos[$telcoIndex]['Call Promo'] = array();
            $telcos[$telcoIndex]['Data Promo'] = array();
            $telcos[$telcoIndex]['SMS Promo'] = array();
        }

        if($callId != $row['callId']) {
            $callIndex++;
            $callId = $row['callId'];

            //add the model to the console
            $telcos[$telcoIndex]['Call Promo'][$callIndex]['Call Name'] = $row['callName'];

            //setup the title array
            $telcos[$telcoIndex]['Call Promo'][$callIndex]['Call'] = array();

            //add the game to the current console and model
            $telcos[$telcoIndex]['Call Promo'][$callIndex]['Call'][] = array(
                'Keyword'     => $row['callKeyword'],
                'Description' => $row['callDescription'],
                'Number'      => $row['callNumber'],
                'Validity'    => $row['callValidity'],
                'Price'       => $row['callPrice']
                );
        }

        if($dataId != $row['dataId']) {
            $dataIndex++;
            $dataId = $row['dataId'];

            //add the model to the console
            $telcos[$telcoIndex]['Data Promo'][$dataIndex]['Data Name'] = $row['dataName'];

            //setup the title array
            $telcos[$telcoIndex]['Data Promo'][$dataIndex]['Data'] = array();

            //add the game to the current console and model
            $telcos[$telcoIndex]['Data Promo'][$dataIndex]['Data'][] = array(
                'Keyword'      => $row['dataKeyword'],
                'Description'  => $row['dataDescription'],
                'Number'       => $row['dataNumber'],
                'Validity'     => $row['dataValidity'],
                'Volume'       => $row['dataVolume'],
                'Price'        => $row['dataPrice']
            );
        }

        if($smsId != $row['smsId']) {
            $smsIndex++;
            $smsId = $row['smsId'];

            //add the model to the console
            $telcos[$telcoIndex]['SMS Promo'][$smsIndex]['SMS Name'] = $row['smsName'];

            //setup the title array
            $telcos[$telcoIndex]['SMS Promo'][$smsIndex]['SMS'] = array();

            //add the game to the current console and model
            $telcos[$telcoIndex]['SMS Promo'][$smsIndex]['SMS'][] = array(
                'Keyword'      => $row['smsKeyword'],
                'Description'  => $row['smsDescription'],
                'Number'       => $row['smsNumber'],
                'Validity'     => $row['smsValidity'],
                'Price'        => $row['smsPrice']
            );
        }
    }

    mysqli_free_result($result);
}

echo json_encode($telcos);

mysqli_close($mysqli);
?>
```

I really don't know why this is happening.

Comment: Please provide example data, preferable in the form of ' CREATE TABLE ...` and `INSERT INTO ... VALUES ...` sql statements

Comment: Thx, but with this example data your query returns zero records.

Comment: Err how is that possible? I already have the data. Check: http://j4hm.t15.org/ios/subscription.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks telcoId is primary unique in telco table, but can be multiple in other tables (which makes sense), unfortunately if you try to join single (1) to multiple1 (2) to multiple2 (2) to multiple3 (3), it'd create 1 * 2 * 2 * 3 = 12 rows, which explains the messy multiple2 and multiple3.

So instead of doing that single DB call, you'll be looking at less efficiency by running separate queries, getting the telco info first, then making individual DB calls for each telco on telcoCall, telcoData, telcoSMS.

Or if you just want the speed and don't care about clean code, you can just use what you have right now, but stack up the if conditions:

EDIT 1: Edited to fix logic flaw, for some reason Gaussian elimination comes to mind

```
// Stacking order determined by your SQL ORDER BY: t.telcoName, c.callName, d.dataName, s.smsName

if($telcoId == $row['telcoId']) continue;
//telco stuff...

if($callId == $row['callId']) continue;
//call stuff...

if($dataId == $row['dataId']) continue;
//data stuff...

if($smsId == $row['smsId']) continue;
//sms stuff...
```

EDIT 2: Another slower way that requires less brainwork

```
if($telcoId != $row['telcoId']) {
    //telco stuff...
    callArrayTemp = array();
    dataArrayTemp = array();
    smsArrayTemp = array();
}
if(!in_array($row['callId'], callArrayTemp[])) {
    callArrayTemp[] = $row['callId'];
    //call stuff...
}
if(!in_array($row['dataId'], dataArrayTemp[])) {
    dataArrayTemp[] = $row['dataId'];
    //data stuff...
}
if(!in_array($row['smsId'], smsArrayTemp[])) {
    smsArrayTemp[] = $row['smsId'];
    //sms stuff...
}
```

Comment: You are right, logic failure there, I'll repair it by introducing an array.

Answer (score 1):

yep Scott was right, that snippet was just the tip of the ice berg, so I finish what he suggested eliminating the redundant entries leaving with unique ones.
https://gist.github.com/jwara/fdc805240cf03027ae20 -- code is kind of not clean but subject to optimizations

http://cl.ly/image/2I3v2O29341J/o